# Create a control group in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains a set of attributes of a user that was exposed to a specific version of an application, including their country and the first date they used the application.

I am trying to create a control group from a population that was not exposed to this specific application version, and to have the same # of players by country and date of use of the other application version. I have two tables:

1. Test table:
   Contains Count(Distinct(User_ID)), Country, Connection_Date
2. Population table:
   User_ID, Country, Connection_Date

This is the query that I am currently using:

```sql
SELECT user_id,
connection_date, 
       country
FROM
  (
    SELECT user_id, 
           connection_date, 
           country,  
           row_number() OVER (partition by country, connection_date ORDER BY user_id) as rownumber 
    FROM table2
  ) sub
JOIN  table 1 on table2.country = table1.country
               and table2.connection_date = table1.connection_date
               AND
               and t2.acct_count >= rownumber
;
```

However, the results are returning a table with MANY duplicate rows (~100,000x the expected number).

Comment: This question is similar to the question posed here however I have been unable to replicate the answer to pull the table that I need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173508/sql-query-constructing-a-control-group

Comment: Please provide sample data + expected results to create a [mre].

Comment: And AFAIK Snowflake != SQL Server and should therefore not be tagged as such.